spss how to modify a variable when making a graph
I'm making a boxplot in spss about month since hire and gender.
I was wondering if its possible to change the months unit to years in the chart builder screen for example by adding a /12 anywhere, I cant seem to find anything when I look it up. the chartbuilder screen
